# How to Open Iframe On Button Click Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Preview Testing</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .buttonDownload {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: #1d71ff;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 15px;
   margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    align-items: center;
}
.down-button{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.buttonDownload:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.buttonDownload:before, .buttonDownload:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 52%;
}

/* Download box shape  */
.buttonDownload:before {
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px;
}

/* Download arrow shape */
.buttonDownload:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
   margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: -7px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    animation: downloadArrow 2s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:before {
    border-color: #4CC713;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:after {
    border-top-color: #4CC713;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.milkparagraph{
    color: #FF4500; 
    font-size: 19px; 
    margin: 15px;
}
.milkdownbox{
    border: 2px solid #365194; 
    padding: 0px 5% 7px 2%; 
    border-radius: 12px;  
    margin: 17px 0% 20px; 
    width: fit-content;
}

/* keyframes for the download icon anim */
@keyframes downloadArrow {
    /* 0% and 0.001% keyframes used as a hackish way of having the button frozen on a nice looking frame by default */
    0% {
        margin-top: -7px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    0.001% {
        margin-top: -15px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        margin-top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
    </style>

  

    <div class="syltp">
       

          <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){ 
        if(!$('#iframe').length) {
                $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GEsC2NXwLjvV4N2JCPqAqAxqMEt3uro0/preview" width="700" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"></iframe>');
        }
    });   
});
</script>
           <h4> <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans';"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-sticky-note"></i>Preview without jquery</span></h4>
          <div class="down-button" id="button"><b class="buttonDownload">PREVIEW</b></div>
          <br />
<div id="iframeHolder"></div>
        
         
        
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How to open iframe only on when the button is clicked without using jquery `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`

here when we open a website the iframe should not load it should load only when the button is clicked

My present code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Preview Testing</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .buttonDownload {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: #1d71ff;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 15px;
   margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    align-items: center;
}
.down-button{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.buttonDownload:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.buttonDownload:before, .buttonDownload:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 52%;
}

/* Download box shape  */
.buttonDownload:before {
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px;
}

/* Download arrow shape */
.buttonDownload:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
   margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: -7px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    animation: downloadArrow 2s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:before {
    border-color: #4CC713;
}

.buttonDownload:hover:after {
    border-top-color: #4CC713;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.milkparagraph{
    color: #FF4500; 
    font-size: 19px; 
    margin: 15px;
}
.milkdownbox{
    border: 2px solid #365194; 
    padding: 0px 5% 7px 2%; 
    border-radius: 12px;  
    margin: 17px 0% 20px; 
    width: fit-content;
}

/* keyframes for the download icon anim */
@keyframes downloadArrow {
    /* 0% and 0.001% keyframes used as a hackish way of having the button frozen on a nice looking frame by default */
    0% {
        margin-top: -7px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    0.001% {
        margin-top: -15px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        margin-top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
    </style>

  

    <div class="syltp">
       

          <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){ 
        if(!$('#iframe').length) {
                $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GEsC2NXwLjvV4N2JCPqAqAxqMEt3uro0/preview" width="700" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"></iframe>');
        }
    });   
});
</script>
           <h4> <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans';"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-sticky-note"></i>Preview without jquery</span></h4>
          <div class="down-button" id="button"><b class="buttonDownload">PREVIEW</b></div>
          <br />
<div id="iframeHolder"></div>
        
         
        
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

it is my present code if I add the above-mentioned jquery its works fine but here I removed it now it's not working

so I want to work it without jquery

[image]

**That sticky sidebar should auto-scroll with the main content but when I used to frame the sidebar not scrolling down. It also block my comment frame**

Comment: Did You Mean To Stick Sidebar In The IFrame

Comment: I Mean Scroll Sidebar When You Scrolling Inside The IFrame

Comment: I mean that when I used your code my all other frames(comment etc..) are not showing and also my right portion with auto-scroll when the main content scrolls that are also not working so I want a different code

Answer (score 0):

Check this, Is this what do you need?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button.openIframe");
const frame = document.getElementById("frame");

btn.addEventListener("click", toggleIframe);

function toggleIframe(){
  var src = "https://www.jqueryscript.net/";
  frame.classList.toggle("d-none");
  btn.classList.toggle("opened");
  if(btn.classList.contains("opened")){
    btn.innerHTML = "Close IFrame";
    src = prompt("Enter a Source :", "https://www.jqueryscript.net/");
  }
  else{
    btn.innerHTML = "Open IFrame";
  }
  frame.src = src;
}
```

```css
.d-none{ display:none; }
```

```html
<button class="openIframe">Open IFrame</button>
<iframe id=frame class="d-none" width="100%" height="60%">
</iframe>
```

Or Same in a Better Way ( **Update** )

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#load");
const src = document.querySelector("#src");
const frame = document.querySelector("#frame");

btn.addEventListener("click", toggleFrame);
function toggleFrame(){
  frame.src = "about:blank";
  if(src.value !== null){
    src.classList.toggle("d-none");
    btn.classList.toggle("opened");
    frame.src = src.value;
    frame.classList.toggle("d-none");
    
    if(btn.classList.contains("opened"))
      btn.innerHTML = "Close";
    else
      btn.innerHTML = "Load";
  }
}
```

```css
.d-none{ display:none; }
```

```html
<input id=src placeholder="Enter a SRC" value="https://www.jqueryscript.net/"><button id=load>Load</button>
<iframe id=frame class=d-none width="100%"></iframe>
```

[iFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: hi I copied the code but it's not working it worked on the code snippet but when I copied a used in vs it not working

Comment: Then the problem is with your web, it should work, Try this  rightclick>inspect and open dev tools in your browser and goto console and see, is there any errors

Comment: Make Sure You are Using this CSS code `.d-none{ display: none; }` and what is not working can you send a screen shot.

Comment: ok now its work but i don't want that input box how it can done without that input box

Comment: ok thanks i have add another display none for input now everything works fine

Comment: This code making an error in the existing code my sidebar wrapping not working due to this code is any other way to do ir

Comment: Can u send a screenshot pls

Comment: I have added the screenshot when I used the iframe my sidebar is not scrolling auto with the main content @QxtN

Comment: when i used this code all my other frame blocked such as my comment frame scroll frame are now no working when I used  this code